Error Setting typeRoots in tsconfig.json in a React Native project
under the compilerOptions when I add typeRoots, it gives me the below error

Cannot find type definition file for 'react-native'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point of type library 'react-native' specified in compilerOptions

The error comes when I add typeRoots
"react-native": "0.74.2",
"@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.5",
Here's my tsconfig
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "./node_modules/@types/react-native",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./type-definitions",
      "./theme.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react-native"
  }
}


what is in your tsconfig.json?

added @MichaelSivolobov

have you find any solution?
